What's the name of a horror movie about dark fairy tales?
I just remember:

It's in English
Begins with a group of friends going to travel
They went to a shack
Has a blonde woman
Has spirits
Has a fat boy (one of friends)
Has a baby
A mountain [i guess] with many stone statues forming a circle
The baby disappear and they gonna look for the baby
They go to some rooms [in the shack] and many fairy tales with a dark vision become real. The witch of Hansel and Gretel cut the tongue of one of them and the ear of the other
A girl plays the sleeping beauty and die


Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

It is called Black Forest (2012). One of my favorite movies.

Black Forest is a 2012 Syfy fantasy/horror film. The story, set in Germany, revolves around a group of strangers who sign up for a tour of of a 'black forest' where the Grimm fairy tales were supposedly written. The tour includes something of a mystical seance intended to communicate with fairies. The ritual ends up transporting the group to a parallel universe, where the Grimm characters are alive... and angry.




